перевод из 3д проекции в 2д
Есть сцена с классической камерой проекция + вид + модель.
Задача: отрисовка объекта (текста) не в пространстве 3д мира, а в пространстве  2д экрана.
Пример: выделяем объект в 3д проекции, и текстовая информация должна рисоваться в проекции Орто как-бы рядом с выделенным объектом.
Сейчас приходиться рисовать текст в 3д пространстве и поворачивать лицом к камере. Не то.
Предполагаю, что именно через матрицы можно перевести координаты текстового блока в экранные.
Спасибо.

Отрисовква в opengl всегда происходит в 3д пространстве. Для работы с 2д пространством имеет смысл использовать ортографическую проекцию glm::ortho с константной третьей координатой.

Чтобы переключиться из 3d в 2d:
    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
    Gl.glLoadIdentity();
    Glu.gluOrtho2D(0, width, height, 0);
    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
    Gl.glLoadIdentity();
    // Отрисовка текстуры с текстом.

Перевод оконных координат (x,y) в пространственные (x,y,z) и обратно:
    Gl.glGetIntegerv(Gl.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    Gl.glGetDoublev(Gl.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
    Gl.glGetDoublev(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
    
    // Из 2d в 3d
    Glu.gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, 
                     viewport, out objX, out objY, out objZ);

    // Из 3d в 2d
    Glu.gluProject(objX, objY, objZ, modelview, projection, 
                   viewport, out winX, out winY, out winZ);



Спасибо.
Ваш ответ навел меня на правильные мысли и все получилось.
Позже постараюсь оформить удобоваримый код для будущих поколений.
